# UDP connections with no foreign address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, udp, netstat

Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ netstat -anu | less
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39262           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37225           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47490           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47500           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33169           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35219           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55714           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33190           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35240           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41392           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43465           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45532           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59877           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37383           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57865           0.0.0.0:* 
...
```

None of the UDP "connections" are in the LISTEN state, but none of them have a foreign address. What does this output mean?

Comment: "_UDP Connections_" There is no such thing.

Comment: @RonMaupin, that's why I put it in quotes :) See first line of netstat output. Whatever you call these things.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is stateless. Those are processes that have called the `recvfrom()` system call to wait for an incoming datagram on the ports indicated in the local address column. If you want to see the PID/Program name run `netstat -anup` (as root).

Comment: So, they are listening to incoming UDP packets, even though the state is not LISTEN?

Comment: I explained it incorrectly. `netstat` is providing information about sockets, not processes. A socket that uses the UDP protocol has no state information. The process is in some sense "listening" by calling `recvfrom()` etc. but there is no state to the socket.